# Adobe Launch: GTAG events (view_item etc)

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js, adobe-launch

I'm struggling with gtag ecom events setup in Adobe Launch (custom code tag type) for Google Ads.
Basically I'm adding event data to dataLayer (gtag('event'...)) and nothing happens, at least in network tab however I'm sure there has to be a request sending the event data.

I have never done it before using Adobe Launch.
In GTM for enhanced-ecom events you have to add a tag with a trigger. So I think since event data is indeed being added to dataLayer I have to figure out how to send this data "manually" (without gtm).

```
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXXX');
gtag('event', conf['type'], {
   'value': conf['price'],
   'items': [
       {
           'id': conf['products'],
           'google_business_vertical': 'retail'
       }]
});
```

data is being added to dataLayer just fine:

[dataLayer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtFic.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Is gtag() defined?
2. If it's not defined, I strongly suggest to use this extension: [https://docs.acronym.com/analytics/adobe-launch/gtag#:~:text=An%20Acronym%20built%20Adobe%20Launch,Global%20Site%20Tag%2C%20or%20gtag](https://docs.acronym.com/analytics/adobe-launch/gtag#:%7E:text=An%20Acronym%20built%20Adobe%20Launch,Global%20Site%20Tag%2C%20or%20gtag).
3. Once installed, the extension will allow a new type of Actions in your rules.
4. You make an action to deploy the library like so:
   [image]
5. Then you make another action, after this, to set values or send events. Well, after the library is deployed, you may as well start doing things in JS if that's the preference.